# ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE with EXTRA_OUTPUT creates handled "Handling Media Storage Error"

Tags: android, android-camera, android-external-storage

I'm calling my camera via `startActivityForResult` with `android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and `android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` want to get the fullsize captured image back in my `onActivityResult`

But the moment I click on the checkmark after taking the picture, the moment when it should be delivered back, I get an error message which loosely translates to "Camera error - There has been a problem while saving one of your images or clips" - I can close the dialog or send feedback to the Google Dev team.

Logcat output at this moment is:

```
09-01 22:01:46.157  24523-24523/com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/CAM_FatalErrorHandler﹕ Handling Media Storage Failure:
java.lang.Exception
        at com.android.camera.FatalErrorHandlerImpl.onMediaStorageFailure(FatalErrorHandlerImpl.java:37)
        at com.android.camera.PhotoModule.onError(PhotoModule.java:274)
        at com.android.camera.PhotoModule.onCaptureDone(PhotoModule.java:1289)
        at com.android.camera.PhotoModule$8.onClick(PhotoModule.java:593)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4781)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19873)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
09-01 22:01:46.158  24523-24523/com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/CAM_CameraUtil﹕ Show fatal error dialog
```

My code (cleaned of irrelevant parts):

```
private File tmpFile;
private Uri tmpFileURI;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    //  TempFile needs to be created for the camera to store the fullsize captured image
    //  tmpFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + MainActivity.APP_BASE_FOLDER + "/tmp.jpg");
    try
    {
        tmpFile = File.createTempFile("my_app", ".jpg");
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tmpFileURI = Uri.fromFile(tmpFile);

    chooseCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

            takePicture = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            takePicture.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tmpFileURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePicture, CreateModifiyEventFragment.CHOOSE_BY_CAMERA);//zero can be replaced with any action code

        }
    });


    chooseLibrary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

            pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, CreateModifiyEventFragment.CHOOSE_BY_LIBRARY);//one can be replaced with any action code

        }
    });

}
```

The seen constants are declared like this:

```
public final static int CHOOSE_BY_CAMERA = 1;
public final static int CHOOSE_BY_LIBRARY = 0;
```

The callback code is never reached, so I'm just going to spare you more code.
You can see I tried it via tmpFile and a normal File on external storage.

Permissions are set also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have no idea what triggers this error or what I am missing out. I used other SO answers to create this code, and I don't see any differences.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance SO!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File.createTempFile()` is unlikely to give you something useful on Android. More importantly, you have no way of knowing if the third-party camera app can write there. Choose a location on external storage (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()` or `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`):

```
package com.commonsware.android.camcon;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import java.io.File;

public class CameraContentDemoActivity extends Activity {
  private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST=1337;
  private File output=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File dir=
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

    output=new File(dir, "CameraContentDemo.jpeg");
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));

    startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                  Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(output), "image/jpeg");
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you do not need the `CAMERA` permission, as you are not taking pictures — you are asking a third-party app to take pictures.

Comment: I tried `//tmpFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + MainActivity.APP_BASE_FOLDER + "/tmp.jpg");` as you can see, with the same error. But `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)` seems to resolve the error. Can you tell me why? Shouldn't the camera be able to write to the first location?

Comment: @LilaQ: Never use string concatenation to create file paths. Use the appropriate `File` constructors. My guess is that what you have there results in an invalid path (e.g., double `/`, missing `/`).

Comment: I logged out the path to make sure it is valid. Or is the camera considered outside of my application, thus not having write rights on externalStorageDirectory?

Comment: @LilaQ: "Or is the camera considered outside of my application" -- yes, as that is not your app. "thus not having write rights on externalStorageDirectory?" -- I would expect most, if not all, camera apps to hold `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.